# Override AppDelegate of Objective-C from swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

I have a mostly objective-c app (Cordova-based, but that shouldn't matter). And I'm writing a small Swift library.

In this library I need to override a few AppDelegate methods, like `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

I've tested my swift library in a pure-swift project and I'm simply throwing my code inside the `AppDelegate.swift` file. Ideally the library is independent and I have some some of `AppDelegate+mylibrary.swift` that is in charge of getting access to those AppDelegate methods without importing the swift itself into the objective-c `AppDelegate.m`.

Any thoughts as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like circular references...

Comment: Overriding app delegate methods in a library doesn't really make sense.  If you want to do something in your library when the app enters the background then you should add an observer to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`

Comment: Or just expose methods that do it and let the client call those methods.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something like https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2Bnotification.h but having that in swift

Comment: Example of what?  Registering for notifications or creating methods?

Comment: creating method to register for notifications in swift for an appdelegate that is in obj-c

Comment: Any have a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.